# Execute command from unity lens

Tags: unity, lenses

I am trying to create a unity lens, how to execute a command when we select an entry from unity-lens
in the following code 
results.append(url,            icon,
            category,
            mime-type,
            text,
            comment,
            drag and drop url)
i tried to set file://, but it opens the file with text editor (if it is not readable with text editor it do nothing)
Please help

Thank you
Vishnu V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to the **activate-uri** signal to perform actions on a result displayed in a lens.

**Using Python**

First, you need to connect the **activate-uri** signal in the Daemon's **init** function (where you connect the **search-changed** and **filters-changed**)

```
self.scope.connect ("activate-uri", self.activate_uri)
```

Then, create a **activate_uri** function in the Daemon.

```
def activate_uri(self, scope, uri):
  #Do stuff with uri here
  return Unity.ActivationResponse (handled = Unity.HandledType.HIDE_DASH, goto_uri = '')
```

This function takes the scope object and the **url** parameter from the result.  **url** does not necessarily need to be a uri, but must be text.  You can do whatever you want with the text in the function.  At the end of the function, you need to return the **Unity.ActivationResponse** as detailed above in order to close the dash.

Have a look at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~markjtully/+junk/calendar-lens/view/30/calendar-lens-daemon.py line 101 & 274-296 for an example of this in action.

**Using Quickly or unity-singlet**

With quickly, it is even easier: Add a function

```
def handle_uri(self, scope, uri): 
  # Do stuff with the uri here
```

to your lens class (in __init__.py). It will be automatically connected to the signal, you do not have to take care of this. Don't forget to add from gi.repository import Unity to your import statements.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i created lens using quickly edit ( source: http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/). But there is no Daemon class or init function. please help

Comment: @VishnuV: With quickly, it is even easier: Add a function `def handle_uri(self, scope, uri):` to your lens class (in `__init__.py`) with the content described by Teester for the `activate_uri` function. Tt will be automatically connected to the signal, you do not have to take care of this. Don't forget to add `from gi.repository import Unity` to your import statements.